# Pre-process non-image data to feed into Tensorflow DNN

Tags: python, tensorflow

I have a large amount of non-image data spread across several delimited files which I want to use as inputs to a DNN in TensorFlow. The data need some pre-processing, so I am trying to use the [CIFAR10](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/tutorials/deep_cnn/index.html#cifar-10-model) example in the TensorFlow source as an example because it has pre-processing, it processes multiple files, and queues data for the model.

I cannot figure out how the data should be represented given that I'll have multiple FeatureColumns and the data are read record by record.

My input data look like below, delimited by '|'. The first column I want to pre-process, the result of which is two values; these values will then convert into Tensors with `tf.contrib.layers.sparse_column_with_hash_bucket`; the second is a real-valued column which I want to convert with `tf.contrib.layers.real_valued_column`; and the third is the label I want to predict.

`uywohy|12.3|0
asdfsvjlk|2.2|1
nlnliu|1.0|1
nlwljw|9.6|0`

My plan is to read the data with `tf.TextLineReader`, split the data on the delimiter, and then pre-process. The example code starts [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/image/cifar10/cifar10_input.py#L79).

```py
# Read in and pre-process a single record
DELIMITER = "|"
reader = tf.TextLineReader()
unparsed_record = reader.read()
col1, col2, label = unparsed_record.split(DELIMITER)
result.label = tf.cast(label, tf.int32)
col1_a, col1_b = _preprocess(col1)
# How to convert col1_a, col1_b, and col2 into a Tensor?
```

However, I'm not sure how to then re-assemble the data (col1_a, col1_b, and col2) into something that can be fed into the model. The CIFAR10 model doesn't make use of `feed_dict` so I don't see how the assemble the data.

Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `tf.learn` which requires a input function that populates the mappings from feature columns to tensors or sparse tensors. Here is an example: https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/r0.11/tensorflow/examples/learn/wide_n_deep_tutorial.py

Comment: Thanks. I have been trying to use the wide-n-deep tutorial and mix those parts with the CIFAR-10 example. My problem is that I have data distributed across lots of files and need to pre-process each record before feeding it into the model. It's not clear to me how to do that pre-processing with `tf.learn`.

Comment: I think tf.learn cannot do that preprocessing. You have to write your own processing program (or even a pipeline) like that in the inception model: https://github.com/tensorflow/models/blob/master/inception/inception/data/build_imagenet_data.py